# concurrent curl POST requests

Tags: bash, shell, unix, concurrency

What's the quickest way to create concurrent curl requests? I have a app which accepts POST requests and would like to do some load testing

I would like to run the following cURL command concurrently and not sequentially

```
 curl -d "param1=value1&param2=value2" http://example.com/test
```

Thanks

Comment: Scripting languages can be good for these types of things -- Ruby, Python, Perl. I could write something like this in a few lines in Ruby...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about [`ApacheBench`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/programs/ab.html)? You've probably already got it installed.

Comment: +1.  very easy to use apache bench, just download the apache source, compile it, go into bin and use the following as an example command
ab -n 100000 -c 450 -T 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' -p goodjson.txt  http : // yourwebsitetohit/

Answer (score 1):

I am not confident but spawning multiple processes in the bachground?

```
nohup curl -parameters &
```

For load testing perhaps you need something like multi-threading, you might also want to research for already available tools.

Answer (score 0):

I do this kind of thing (generating concurrent POST requests) with a few small perl scripts I wrote:

http://patrick.net/sprocket/rwt.html

I'm planning to port it to python, but the perl version works pretty well right now.